# Logitech Gaming Software - script "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1"?

Tags: logitech-gaming-software

Either I'm doing something wrong, or it's an LGS bug.
I want to check through a simple script where I press Mouse button 1 and get a message on the keyboard lcd screen
but LGS only responds to the Mouse button 4 and above.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, arg)
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
ClearLCD ()
OutputLCDMessage("Hello world1")
OutputLCDMessage("Hello world2")
    end
end
```

Comment: `EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)` should be above `function OnEvent(event, arg)`

Comment: Thank for your answer! I've tried, but seems not working.